# edit .tf variable files using bash script

Tags: bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have a big file of variables in .tf file and I want to change values using bash script .

like my file have many chunks like this and I want to change each one step by step .what will be best practice to change terraform file variables values ?

```
variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "name"
      size         = "size"
      vpc          = ""
    },
    spoke2 = {
      name         = "dummy"
      size         = "size2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

Set the variables before proceeding

```
spke="spoke1" # The spoke we are concerned with
var="size" # The variable within the spoke section we are concerned with
val="size1" # The value we want to change to.
clp="azure" # Either azure or aws
```

Pass these variable into GNU awk with -v

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" -v clp="$clp"'
      /variable/ { 
                                      cloudp=gensub(/(^variable[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0) # Pull out the cloud provider
                 }
      /spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { 
                                        spoke=$1 # Track the spoke section
                                     } 
          spoke==spke && $1==var && cloudp ~ clp { # If spoke is equal to the passed spoke and the first space separated field is equal to the variable and clp is equal to the passed cloud provider (clp) we want to change (var)
                                        $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) # Substitute the value for the value passed (val)
                                     }1' file
```

One liner

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" -v clp="$clp" '/variable/ { cloudp=gensub(/(^variable[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0) } /spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var && cloudp ~ clp { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file
```

If you have a recent version of GNU awk, you can commit the changes to the file by simply adding the -i flag and so:

```
awk -i -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" -v clp="$clp" '/variable/ { cloudp=gensub(/(^variable[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0) } /spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var && cloudp ~ clp { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file
```

Otherwise:

```
awk -v spke="$spke" -v var="$var" -v val="$val" -v clp="$clp" '/variable/ { cloudp=gensub(/(^variable[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0) } /spoke[[:digit:]][[:space:]]=/ { spoke=$1 } spoke==spke && $1==var && cloudp ~ clp { $0=gensub(/(^.*=[[:space:]]")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\1"val"\\3",$0) }1' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```

Comment: awk is making a issue , If I run awk command 2 times , only last one change is applied . like I first run name change and then size . and only name change worked

Comment: I am using one liner

Comment: You have to ensure that the changes are committed with awk -i or with the temp file move as in the last example of second last example.

Comment: I am using  `otherwise` option , as  -i  is not valid command for me

Comment: sir almost done , there is just a small issues . if there are two variables with same name awk is changing both . I have updated my question . kindly have a look.

Comment: or If I can check if its first occurrence or 2nd. So when i want to change 1st occurrence I can eaily or 2nd

Comment: OK, I've amended. You now have to pass cloud provider either aws or azure.

Comment: fixed that as well thank you so much.  now there is last case which is not handled with that. should I ask a separate question sir or can you look that aswell if I edit question?

Comment: Accept the answer on this with an up vote and ask another question

Comment: sir kindly have a look . Posted this one     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268664/edit-terraform-variable-files-using-awk-for-a-specific-pattern

Comment: What's the difference, the subnet?

Comment: there is no spoke , but just `default`    , I have added pattern .but there will so many as same pattern  so I need variable name as well

Comment: sir can you look into small issue ?

Answer (score 3):

If you own the file and can produce it from scratch, rather than editing an existing one, you could use the following approach.

```
cat << EOF > main.tf.sh
variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name    = "AZ-${region}-Spoke1-GW"
      size       = "Standard_B1ms"
      .. 
    }
  }
}
EOF
chmod +x main.tf.sh

export region=EU
. ./main.tf.sh > main.tf
```

Though it's limited to a certain kind of scenarios, but very simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for answer , but I only can edit it using `bash script`

Answer (score 1):

If you store your variables in a [Terraform JSON format](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html), I'd recommend using something JSON-aware, such as [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), rather than naively modifying the JSON using `sed`/`awk` etc. That way you should be able to reliably maintain your JSON format.

If you need to maintain the original format, which I understand is HCL, maybe write a script using an HCL parser, such as [this one](https://pypi.org/project/pyhcl/)

Comment: Sadly its not json and Its been 6 days I am doing research :(  its formate is `.ts`  . Any idea if I want to change   `.tf`  variables file values  ?

Comment: If the original format is HCL, I think you'll find parsers for various different scripting languages. Failing that, you may be able to get away with sed/awk for simple cases.

Comment: kindly can you please give a small example of `pyhcl` ?

Comment: I've not used it, I confess